# How to redirect non exist function in a controller to index function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I set 404 not found view to undefined function globally

But for abcController below
if i run :
https://base_url/abcController/ABC -> redirect to index function
how to specialize this controller so it can be redirect to index function without getting 404 not found ?

```
 Class abcController extends My_Controller {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
           
        }

        function index() {
            $this->load->view('checkingOS');
        }   

        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Application>config>config.php

```
$route['404_override'] = 'Main_Controller/page404';
```

Application>controller>Main_Controller.php>page404 ( FUNCTION )

```
public function page404(){
  redirect(base_url());
}
```